# SDKSetting.plist not found after upgrading xamarin to 5.9.8 version

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am experiencing below error after upgrading xamarin to 5.9.8 version

```
"Error MT0024: Could not find required file /Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist. (MT0024)"
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed below steps and it worked for me .

> 1) Remove the spacing between Xcode Name. In my case, it was Xcode 7.2.1 so renamed this with Xcode7.2.1

2) Clean and build the solution.